# Jackson deserialize polymorphic types not under my control

Tags: java, jackson, polymorphism, unmarshalling

I want to (un)marshal an Object that contains a field of [this type](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.14.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/NamedNode.html). While the serialization works well i am not able to deserialize it.
The implementing classes are not under my control. I guess in general it is not possible to deserialize to the original implementing class due to missing constructors and or setters.

On the other hand i want to save all information (as java object) contained in the json.

What are my options to achieve this, are there best or good practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Jackson Mixins to fake a `@JsonDeserialize(using=CustomDeserializer.class)` annotation on the class/field in question.
Then you can try to create the instances yourself in the given deserializer class.

```
// I'm not sure whether annotations (@JsonTypeInfo) on class level are supported as well to allow the polymorphistic type decision.
abstract class MixIn {

  // make constructor usable if available
  MixIn(@JsonProperty("id") int a, @JsonProperty("name") String b) { }

  @JsonDeserialize(using=CustomDeserializer.class) abstract TypeX getTypeX();
  
}
```

And then you can use it like this

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(TypeXContainer.class, MixIn.class);
```

Doks: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations